# How to construct iterators of the container

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

I want to write my own container, but I stumble on creating iterators during `begin()` and `end()`.

Let's imagine that it's equivalent to `std::vector`, but not specialized for `bool`. When I type `std::vector<int>::iterator::` intellisense doesn't show any constructor. How do they construct iterator on `begin()` and `end()` calls? I guess that `iterator` class should be member to the container, am I wrong?

I believe constructor(s) are made private and the container is made a friend of the iterator. Nevertheless, I think I'm getting something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::iterator` means that there's something in the `std::vector<T>` class called "iterator". It could be a typedef:

```
template<typename T> class vector {

public:

    typedef {{something}} iterator;
};
```

(Note: For the purposes of this question, I'm ignoring the `Allocator` template parameter, it's not relevant).

Or, it could be a full blown inner class.

```
template<typename T> class vector {

public:

    class iterator {

        // ...
    };
};
```

It could also be a few other tihngs. It does not matter which is the case. The only thing you're guaranteed is that when you refer to a `std::vector<T>::iterator`, you get something that meets the requirements of the iterator.

For your container, you are also free to implement your container's iterator in any way that produces the correct result.

However, for your custom iterator, you will find it convenient to have your iterator to [properly inherit from `std::iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/), because `std::iterator` will automatically declare some things that all iterators need to have, if they are to interoperate smoothly with the C++ library.

Finally, as far as "how do they actually get constructed", they could really be constructed in any way. Note that you do not explicitly construct an iterator, you use `begin()`, `end()`, or `find()`, or... So, only the container cares how the iterator needs to be constructed. It could be a public constructor, or a private constructor, this is entirely up to the container.